# Replace special character with an escape preceded special character when String, replaceAll fails

Tags: escaping, character, replacewith

In my java code I want something like if a string input has got any of the special characters mentioned, that should get preceded by a `\`.
Special character set is`{+, -, &&, ||, !, (, ), {, },[, ], ^, "", ~, *, ?, :, \}`. I tried using `inputString.replaceAll(old,new)` but to my surprise its not working, even though I am giving proper values for 'old' and 'new'. 
I put the special chars in a String array, iterated it in a for loop, checked whether it is present in the string, if yes, `input.replaceAll(":","\\:")`. But its not giving me the intended output. Please help.

```
 String[] arr = { "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}",
                    "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "AND", "OR" };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("arr[" + i + "]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + arr[i]);
            System.out.println(search.contains((String) arr[i])
                    + "---------->" + arr[i]);

            if (search.contains((String) arr[i])) {
                System.out.println("..index..."+search.indexOf((String) arr[i]));
                String oldString = (String) arr[i];
                System.out.println("check if it has old string"
                        + search.contains(oldString));
                String newString = new String("\\" + arr[i]);
                System.out
                        .println("About to replace special chars....with..."
                                + newString);

                search = search.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
                String newSearch = new String(search.replaceAll(arr[i],
                        newString));
                System.out
                        .println("Search String after replaceAll is ------------->: "
                                + newSearch);
                System.out.println("--------------"
                        + search.replaceAll(arr[i], newString)
                        + "---------------" + search);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape single backslashes first (before escaping anything else) or you double escape some backslashes.

Example: `1+1`

Replace `+` by `\+` => `1\+1`

Replace `\` by `\\` => `1\\+1` (oops!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have your answer. Today I was trying same. I modified your code to use my solution. Hope its helpful for you.

```
String search = "$&+";

String[] arr = { "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "AND", "OR" };

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 System.out.println("arr[" + i + "]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + arr[i]);
 System.out.println(search.contains((String) arr[i])
         + "---------->" + arr[i]);

 if (search.contains((String) arr[i])) {
     System.out.println("..index..."+search.indexOf((String) arr[i]));
     String oldString = (String) arr[i];
     System.out.println("check if it has old string"
             + search.contains(oldString));
     String newString = new String("\\\\" + arr[i]);
     System.out
             .println("About to replace special chars....with..."
                     + newString);

     search = search.replace("\\" + oldString, newString);
     String newSearch = new String(search);
     System.out
             .println("Search String after replaceAll is ------------->: "
                     + newSearch);

 }
```

}